# increment count using interval timer

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I currently have a macro that has a built in timer that i have coded, and after a set interval it calls a subroutine "increment_count". increment count is a subroutine that just counts up. I was wondering, is it possible for me to use milliseconds? i have tried adding another colon and then milliseconds but it did not seem to work, why? Please help

```
Sub StartTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "increment_count"  

End Sub
```

Thank You

Comment: Excel implicitly converts `Now` to a number. `TimeValue()` returns a number. Find out the intervals and increase the value by number instead of a string. For example `0.000001` is one 10th of a second. so `Application.OnTime Now + 0.000001` would be now + one 10th of a second...

Comment: @mehow; like that? `Application.OnTime Now + (TimeValue("00:00:01") / 1000), "increment_count"`, because this is working.  **Edit:** did not see you edited your comment.

Comment: Any chance you could post your final code as an "Answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.OnTime Now + (TimeValue("00:00:01") / 1000), "increment_count"